# variance operartion error in R

Tags: r

I have tried to operate to this simple problem in R

```
> ex <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
> mean(ex)
[1] 4
> var(ex)
[1] 4.666667
> sd(ex)
[1] 2.160247
```

But that is simple problem.
This is correct answer.

```
var(ex) = 4
sd(ex) = 2
```

What is problem in this case?

Comment: I would guess - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Comment: R returns the sample sd and variance, not the population sd and variance.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck think you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out, R returns the sample variance. There is no built-in function to obtain the population variance as far as I know, but you can easily define it yourself multiplying the result by `(n-1)/n`:

```
 var.pop=function(x, y = NULL, na.rm = FALSE, use){
   n <- ifelse(is.null(dim(x)),length(x),dim(x)[1])
   return(var(x,y,na.rm,use)*(n-1)/n)
 }
```

This function will also calculate the population covariance. You can also define a similar version of the `sd` function or just call `sqrt(var.pop(ex))`.